# Invalid login details in Nodemailer (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, email, gmail

Been trying to implement a simple mail script using **nodemailer** in **node.js**. This implementation is based on the **Gmail API** and I used this [link](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport) as reference. Now I am facing the below error

```
{ [Error: Invalid login]
```

code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 qe3sm505011pbc.73 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535 }

And the fallowing is the code that I used

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var generator = require('xoauth2').createXOAuth2Generator({
    user: 'bharathvijay38',
    clientId: '***************',
    clientSecret: '***************',
    refreshToken: '***************',
    accessToken: '***************'
});

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx',
        pass: '************',
        xoauth2: generator
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx',
    to: 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx',
    subject: 'hello!',
    text: 'Hello there !'
    }, function(error, info){
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }

    console.log("Message sent: "+info);
});
```

I am new to node.js and server side scripting. So please kindly help me out

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `xoauth2` options?

According to [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer)

This is the basic usage

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});
```

Where the user is, your Gmail username and the password is, your Gmail password.

Comment: Have tried this. But it didn't work out. And I get warnings like insecure login and that login is never accepted by google. So I use the xoauth2 method. Thank you

Comment: Do you need to give an Auth object in `createTransport()`? can't you just do `nodemailer.createTransport();` then in mail options provide `From` `To`?